# What's the difference between JavaScript method Document.write() vs document.write()?

Tags: javascript, dom, document

When writing something to HTML, we usually use: `document.write();` ("D" is lowercase).

However, [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) describes the method as `Document.write();` ("D" is uppercase), and it doesn't work when i tried testing it.

Can anyone help explain why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you might see someone referencing `Array.find` (when in fact `.find` only exists on `Array.prototype`), `.write` exists on the *prototype* of Document, not on the Document constructor itself.

```js
console.log(Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty('write'));
```

`document.write` works because `document` inherits from `Document.prototype`.

MDN's usage of `Document.write` is meant to convey that `.write` can be called on any instance of `Document`, even though the document constructor itself doesn't have that property.

It's possible to call `.write` from the prototype, if you wanted:

```js
Document.prototype.write.call(
  document, // call on *this HTML document*
  '<div>foobar</div>' // first argument passed to .write
);
```

Comment: i understand partly what you say, but still a few question: 1, i cann't find trails of the relation of document to Document.prototype in MDN, is this relation self existed? 2, i tried {new Document().write()} which also not working. (but new Document() is an instance of Document which should contain the write() method); 3, i am a newbie language learner, hope not making fool question.

Comment: Only HTML documents can have `.write` called on them; `new Document` won't be enough. (yeah, it'd odd that `.write` exists in Document and not on HTMLDocument) You can use something like [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) if you want